# How to correctly execute find query with comparing on long field in MongoDB?? Error code 2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

My document have some `long` field:

```
{
    "_id" : BinData(3,"qUlr7T//axtyJisrSnDRkw=="),
    ...
    "next-run-date" : "2018-12-23T17:22:59.026Z",
    "next-run-millis" : NumberLong("1540833792947"),
    ...
    "_class" : "...domain.scheduling.ScheduleReportConfiguration"
}
```

I use `Spring Data MongoDB (v2.0.5)` and have a repository:

```
interface ScheduleReportConfigurationRepository extends MongoRepository<ScheduleReportConfiguration, UUID> {

List<ScheduleReportConfiguration> findByNextRunMillisLessThan( long milliseconds )
}
```

When I try to execute it a produced query is:

```
{ "next-run-millis" : { "$lt" : { "$numberLong" : "1544809451462" } } }
```

Question 1: Why it look like that?? When I try to execute it in DB, it no make sense. Why spring don't produce the query like: `{ "next-run-millis" : { "$lt" : NumberLong(1544809451462) } }`??

In any case, both of these queries don't work. By first query I mean the repository method execution in my app integration test,by second - execution the query in mongo shell. The error:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException:
Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'error processing query:
ns=test.scheduleReportConfigurationTree: next-run-millis $lt 1544809451462

No query solutions' on server mongo:27017; nested exception is
com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message
'error processing query: ns=test.scheduleReportConfigurationTree: next-run-millis $lt 1544809451462
```

Question 2: What do I wrong?? How me to make my query worked?? According to the docs, comparing operators should work fine with long.

Thank you for your answers and help.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to make my field indexed.

Comment: I don't know: should I delete the question??